# Put Group header above group instead of beside it in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report group that currently looks like the image. It has row groups as follows:
[image: Report so far]

It grouped in order like this:
Department
Agent
Year
Month

I have removed the columns with department and agent and year. I would like to put the agent and department above the column headers which repeat on each page along with the agent. I tried putting a row above the headers but you can't merge cells when adding a row above there and agent + department is very long. What I want is shown in 2nd image..I put the expression in a text box in the page header but it just repeats the first value on each page and not the actual value.
[image]

How to do? I want it above and not beside to save horizontal space.

Comment: Could you attach a screen grab of your report in design view?

Answer (score 1):

Check these previous answers of mine. If they don't help, post the report design including group properties and I'll see what I can do.

[Grouping in SSRS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122555/grouping-in-ssrs/46124867#46124867)

[Repeat Row group on top of table as table headers between every groups in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55053987/repeat-row-group-on-top-of-table-as-table-headers-between-every-groups-in-ssrs/55054861#55054861)